# Software to transmit sensitive text/image between computer and phone

Tags: encryption

Please recommend a method to do the following:

1. Securely transmit some text (a phrase) or a photo from smartphone to Windows computer.
2. Do the reverse: Securely transmit some text or an image from Windows computer to smartphone.

I want to do this without physically connecting the devices. Ideally using something like OpenPGP.

What I do currently (for non-sensitive data):

I have a **To-Do** app on my phone and it has a web version. I go to the website (from computer) and create a new todo item, with the text I want to access on my phone. I can also attach a photo. Then I can access it on my phone. I can do the reverse: create a Todo item on the phone (or attach a photo), and I can access it from the computer through the website.

Now I want to be able to do something similar but in a secure/encrypted way.

Comment: “Ideally using something like GnuPGP” – so, what’s wrong with GnuPGP?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Why is GnuPGP not the answer to your questions?  Presumably you want something quite like it, but it is missing a few features? What are those features?

Comment: I don't know enough about it but that it does OpenPGP which is what I should have said, i.e. something that uses encryption. You imply that GnuPG is the answer. Can you tell me how please? i.e. How would I use it to transfer some data from windows machine to smartphone and reverse?